# MarshalJSON error , invalid character "g" after top-level

Tags: json, go, marshalling, hashids

I made a custom type for my IDs:

```
type ID uint

func (id ID) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    e, _ := HashIDs.Encode([]int{int(id)})
    fmt.Println(e) /// 34gj
    return []byte(e), nil
}

func (id *ID) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    *id = ID(value.(int64))
    return nil
}
```

I use the HashIDs package to encode my ids so that user wont be able to read them on client side. But I'm getting this error:

> json: error calling MarshalJSON for type types.ID: invalid character 'g' after top-level value

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where that error occure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`34gj` is not a valid JSON and hence not a valid string representation of your ID. You probably want to wrap this with double quotation mark to indicate this is a string, i.e. returning `"34gj"`.

Try:

```
func (id ID) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    e, _ := HashIDs.Encode([]int{int(id)})
    fmt.Println(e) /// 34gj
    return []byte(`"` + e + `"`), nil
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/0ESimzPbAx

Instead of doing it by hand you can also call marshaller for the string, by simply replacing your return with `return json.Marshal(e)`.

My guess would be that `invalid character 'g'` in your error is due to initial part of the value is being treated as a number and then unexpected character occurs.

Comment: Yes, it might... I had tought the marshaller wrap it it self in " " but don't know why this happend... anyway this solved it, thanks

Comment: I hope there's a better explanation for this behavior

Comment: Emad, it can't wrap it for you with `"` automatically as by implementing marshaller you're supposed to provide a valid raw JSON. So you can, for example, return `{"id": "abc"}` (not a string!). Obviously wrapping it with quotes would be wrong. You can always use `return json.Marshal(e)` in your code to provide a valid string representation without worrying about quotes (added this comment to my answer).